# C++ set limit on maximum memory allocation?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory-management, x86, stdvector

I am writing a program in x86 architecture (for technical reasons I cannot use x64). I have designed my program such that it uses under 4GB of RAM memory. However, when I allocate memory for large `std::vector`s I notice that the constructors allocate more memory than necessary and later trim the memory down to the proper amount (tested on smaller memory requirements to be able to observe that). This is a problem, since the brief moment when more RAM is allocated than necessary is crashing the program due to >4GB RAM usage.

Is there a way to prevent the program from dynamically allocating more than a given amount of RAM? If so, how can one set this property in a Visual Studio solution?

Comment: You have not provided enough detail, show us some code. If you want to prevent runtime allocations, then `reserve()` the memory beforehand, or use a statically sized array.

Comment: Or write your own allocator to have complete control.

Comment: *and later trim the memory down to the proper amount* This is actually unusual behaviour. I wouldn't count on this in all cases.

Comment: Obviously you never *actually* have more than 4GiB of memory allocated in a 32-bit process.  Virtual address space is only 4GiB, so the attempt must fail.  (Unless the allocator is buggy and returns overlapping allocations.)

Comment: *trim the memory down to the proper amount* - You mean your code manually uses `resize()` to shrink the allocation?  But since C++ allocators suck and don't implement a `realloc` interface to hand excess memory back to the free list (or the OS), they actually try to allocate + copy.  I've never understood why C++ new/delete has such a terrible design that's incapable of exposing what modern OSes can efficiently do, which std::vector could use under the hood without any changes to its API.

Comment: @PeterCordes The program crashed when trying to allocate more than 4GB. Thank you for mentioning the allocate+copy property of `std::vector`, was not aware of this! In response to that I changed a `vector<vector<struct>>` to `vector<array<struct,N>>` and now there is no memory spike. This solved my problem, thank you.

Comment: Why not use std::pmr allocator with you std containers?

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider  accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the standard `vector` constructor is briefly allocating additional memory to perform a copy operation, as mentioned by [Peter Cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes) in a comment. That's why doing:

```
vector<vector<struct>> myVector(M, vector<struct>(N))
```

may lead to memory allocation problems.

The workarounds that worked for me are:

If required vector size is known before compilation, the following does not produce a memory spike:

```
vector<array<struct,N>> myVector(M)
```

If the vector size needs to stay dynamical, the suggestion of [Mansoor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3476954/mansoor) in the comments also does not produce a memory spike:

```
vector<vector<struct>> myVector(M)
for(int i=0;i<M;i++){
    myVector[i].reserve(N);
    myVector[i].resize(N);
}
```

Comment: `vector<array< struct, N>>` will not let you push arrays of less than or greater than `N`.
If you know the exact size  you do not need to wrap you array into vector. you can directly you vector to hold n structs. This way you mean that you want to hold vector of `array<struct, N>` array size is evaluated at compile time.

Comment: @foragerDev yep, that's for the case when `N` is static and known before compilation.

Comment: but it will still allocate additional memory as its T for vector, vector is a dynamic container. If you know exact size at compile time why use vector? Just use std::array<struct, N>.